# Reference's Copy Local property changes to false during a rebuild of the solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm getting an error that my project can't find a reference. `Copy Local` is originally set to `True`, but after rebuilding the solution, it changes back to `False`:

[image]

Why would this happen? How can I make it stick? I tried editing the project itself:

[image]

However, the reference shows that `Copy Local` is still false after a rebuild.

Comment: interesting.. I don't think I ever saw a simple clean/rebuild action modify the project file, you're sure there's no build event or so that for instance tells the versioning system to reset any changes made? Or something else that could be modifying the file? What happens if you make it read-only?

Comment: The rebuild doesn't modify the project file. `Private` is still `True`. However, when I look at the properties window for the reference, `Copy Local` is set back to false.

Comment: There is no build event. Why would making the file read-only matter?

Comment: Because when I read your question the first time I was under the impression the project file changed on disk - now since you clarified it's only it's in-memory representation (what is reflected in the gui), simply ignore my first comment

Comment: You have the strangest problems.  There is a condition where MSBuild overrides CopyLocal, it is a very obscure one.  You need to provide better diagnostics.  Turn up MSBuild verbosity to Detailed and provide the trace you get in a paste bin.

Comment: @HansPassant Here is the paste bin: http://pastebin.com/4PwLUYfF. The project with the issue is ConsoleTester.

Comment: Sigh, it is just a plain "file not found" error message.  Remove the assembly reference and add it back.

Comment: I had actually already tried that a couple times. Keeps happening.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682096/how-do-i-override-copylocal-private-setting-for-references-in-net-from-msbuil

Answer (score 0):

This could caused by registering the Referenced Assembly to the Global Assembly Cache during the build. If the assembly is found in the global assembly cache, the value for Copy Local is set to false.

See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3101105/1196586