# Stop Visual Studio from copying Nuget Packages in the output dir

Tags: .net, visual-studio, csproj, .net-framework-version

**Disclaimer:** This is a ***.Net Framework*** specific problem, that doesn't happen in .Net Core.

I am currently wokring on a project, that works as an AddIn of a larger project. I'd like to set the output path of my project to the AddIn folder of the larger project then start the larger project with the debug-properties of my project, so I don't have to copy and attach to project each time manually.

Any reference I have is shared with and managed from the larger project, which means i don't have (and should not) copy them to the AddIn Folder.

I included code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50755479/7696590) to my .csproj (VS 19/new format)

```
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <Reference>
    <Private>False</Private>
  </Reference>
  <ProjectReference>
     <Private>False</Private>
  </ProjectReference>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

to exclude project- and regular references, but in .Net Framework all *.dlls* from my Nuget packages are also copied to the output path. I was looking for a way to disable that too, but haven't found one.

**Is there a way to stop *.dlls* from Nuget packages to be copied to the output path in .Net Framework?**

Comment: why do not you publish nuget packages of the project to a AddIn? wont that help?

Comment: @Azzarrel, it would be great if you could accept and upvote :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/5189) github post. Other than that, @Maytham covered it perfectly:

> why do not you publish nuget packages of the project to a AddIn? wont that help?

He's right. That should help. But, just to recap the github post:

You could turn off runtime access from every package:

```js
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.1" ExcludeAssets="runtime" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Or you could do it for all packages:

```js
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <PackageReference ExcludeAssets="runtime" />
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

> Once you have that, make a CopyNuGetDependencies (or whatever you want to call it) project with a different output path. Make sure it reference to all NuGet packages - but without `ExcludeAssets`. It's soley responsable for copying NuGet packages to the output directly.

That should stop all of the issues.

Comment: Thanks. this is the right solution, however it only works on 4.7.2 or newer; 4.7.1 seems to be broken, but I haven't yet dug up a reference that confirms.

Comment: Ofcourse! Happy to help!