# Configure MSBuild to build a solution and for each project put the built dlls into one directory and external libraries into another

Tags: c#, msbuild

I would like to be able to use MSBuild to build my solution and for it to not copy over any third party dlls the projects reference to the output directory.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the `CopyLocal` property to `false` on the reference in Visual Studio. See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c.aspx) for more info on `CopyLocal`. This setting will stop msbuild from copying non-GAC'd references to your bin directory

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682096/how-do-i-override-copylocal-private-setting-for-references-in-net-from-msbuil) is the best solution for me. You can set this way default value for Private property for all references and project references. I'm using it for local & server builds. If you need to disable copying references into your bin dir during compilation using VS2010 you have to set < Private > property to False for every (project) reference directly in the project file. 
Visual Studio and MSBuild set Private properties to True by default.