# Prevent content from being copied

Tags: c#, msbuild

I'm using a custom targets file to prevent superfluous copying when running MSBuild on C# projects in a build server. Originally I started with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682096/how-do-i-override-copylocal-private-setting-for-references-in-net-from-msbuil):

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <Reference>
    <Private>False</Private>
  </Reference>
  <ProjectReference>
    <Private>False</Private>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

This works great for references, but I wasn't able to find any equivalent version to files marked with `Content` or `None` tags.

This is what I've come up with, and unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <Content>
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
  <None>
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

**Example:** I'd like `my_resource.dll` to never copy to the output directory. This is how it's defined within the project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="..\..\..\my_resource.dll">
    <Link>my_resource.dll</Link>
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: which files are you trying to exclude?

Comment: Files that are marked as `Content` or `None` (instead of `Reference` or `ProjectReference`). I have assemblies which are also marked as `Content`. I prefer passing a custom targets file to MSBuild over manually changing all `Content` tags to `Reference` tags, because then I would have to work to maintain this effort.

Comment: If you never want it to copy to the output directory, why do you have it defined with `<CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>`?

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I have hundreds of projects to maintain and I can't control all the code, certainly not educate all the developers. It's much easier and more robust to define a general behavior in a custom targets file than to try and manually edit all the problematic projects.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Sorry, I don't think I understood you - I specify an overriding behavior in the custom file. You can override properties for `Reference` and `ProjectReference`. Why would any other tag be different? I mean, of course `Content` doesn't have the `Private` property, but it has the `CopyToOutputDirectory`, so that one should work.

Comment: I should have written "an overriding behavior" instead of "a general behavior" in my last comment :)